# Recording button like SnapChat

Tags: android, video, record, progress

I want to record video like snapchat, I'm trying to create Record button like this

[image: this]

and also record video when user long press on button and stop recording when user leave it so how can i built it? Please guyz help me!!!

Comment: I tried to implement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187031/record-video-using-surfaceview-and-play-that-video-on-click-button but i didn't got success

Comment: @Komal I have done it for 10 seconds video with simple progress bar

Comment: And I also Play at a time when user click on Play Button!!!

Comment: @Komal for playing you have to manage by yourself

Comment: Ok Can you help me to solve it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116452/discussion-between-komal-and-nisarg).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private static final int MIN_CLICK_DURATION = 600;
private long startClickTime;
private boolean longClickActive;
private boolean recording, pause = false;
private long elapsed;
private long remaningSecs = 0;
private long elapsedSecs = 0;
private Timer timer;

try {

your_button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    final long INTERVAL = 1000;
                    final long TIMEOUT = 10000;
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                            Log.i("ACTION_DOWN", "ACTION_DOWN::" + pause + " " + recording);
                            if (longClickActive == false) {
                                longClickActive = true;
                                startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                            }
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            if (longClickActive == true) {
                                long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
                                if (clickDuration >= MIN_CLICK_DURATION) {
                                    longClickActive = false;
                                    if (pause && !recording) {
                                        pause = false;
                                        if (!prepareMediaRecorder()) {

                                            Log.e("Fail to prapare","");
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                        // work on UiThread for better performance
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {
                                                try {
                                                    mediaRecorder.start();
                                                } catch (final Exception ex) {
                                                    // Log.i("---","Exception in thread");
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

                                        recording = true;
                                        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                remaningSecs -= INTERVAL;

                                                if (remaningSecs == 0) {
                                                    this.cancel();
                                                    try {
                                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void run() {
                                                                recording = false;
                                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                                                                prgrsBar.setProgress(0);

                                                                Log.e("Video captured!","");
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                                    }
                                                    return;
                                                }
                                                elapsedSecs = remaningSecs;
                                                prgrsBar.setProgress((int) (elapsedSecs / 1000));
                                                Log.i(TAG, "Milli::" + (remaningSecs / 1000));

                                            }
                                        };
                                        timer = new Timer();
                                        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, INTERVAL, INTERVAL);

                                    } else {
                                        if (!prepareMediaRecorder()) {

                                             Log.e("Fail in prepare MediaRecorder","");

                                        }
                                        // work on UiThread for better performance
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {
                                                try {
                                                    mediaRecorder.start();

                                                } catch (final Exception ex) {
                                                    // Log.i("---","Exception in thread");
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                        recording = true;
                                        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                elapsed += INTERVAL;
                                                if (elapsed == 11000) {
                                                    this.cancel();
                                                    try {
                                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void run() {
                                                                recording = false;
                                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                                // mediaRecorder.stop(); // stop the recording
                                                                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                                                                prgrsBar.setProgress(0);

                                                                Log.e("Video captured!","");
                                                            }
                                                        });


                                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                                    }
                                                    return;
                                                }
                                                elapsedSecs = 10000 - elapsed;
                                                prgrsBar.setProgress((int) (elapsedSecs / 1000));
                                                Log.i(TAG, "Milli::" + (elapsedSecs / 1000));
                                                remaningSecs = elapsedSecs;
                                                remaningSecs = Math.round(remaningSecs);
                                                elapsedSecs = Math.round(elapsedSecs);
                                            }
                                        };
                                        timer = new Timer();
                                        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, INTERVAL, INTERVAL);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            Log.i("ACTION_UP", "ACTION_UP::" + recording);
                            longClickActive = false;
                            if (recording) {
                                // stop recording and release camera
                                prgrsBar.setProgress((int) (elapsedSecs / 1000));
                                timer.cancel();
                                pause = true;
                                recording = false;
                                remaningSecs = remaningSecs + 1000;
                                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                            }
                            break;
                    }

                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



//  If applicable to you otherwise use your methods to release and prepare 
private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
    try {
        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
            mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.lock(); // lock camera for later use
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException stopException) {
        //handle cleanup here
    }
}

private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {
    mCamera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    //        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
    //                .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P));
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(1, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(strRecordedVideoPath);
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(10000); // Set max duration 10 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); // Set max file size 50M
    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: @Ali Obeid  It depends on your UI

Comment: You added prgrsBar, is it in the button itself?

Comment: @AliObeid your_button is your button in view which you using to capture video