# On android, how to make a snapchat or instagram type camera button?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I'd like to make a button where when it's clicked, the phone takes a picture and when it's pressed, it takes a video (for as long as it's pressed). How would I go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: For taking video you can  refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38202923/3117966)

Comment: Oh wow surprised I couldn't find that. So that happens for "onTouch". I'm guessing for me to implement the picture part, I just take a picture "onClick"? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome and you can take a picture with "onClick"

Comment: If you find any trouble to manage both than you'd implement single tap in "onTouch" with gestureDetector

Comment: have you found out a solution?

Comment: i think chat room is better. i think you should have gotten a notification about the one i created?